# Finding a specific Sub-Matrix of a given Matrix

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, 2d

Let's say I have this 2D array which we will call a Matrix

```
float[,] arr = { {0, 2, 7 },
                 {3, 1, 0 },
                 {6, 2, 4 } };
```

I have to create a function that you give two integers i and j, And it will return a matrix without that i-row and j-column. For example if I pass (0,0) as parameters I will get

```
float [,] newArr = {{1, 0 },
                    {2, 4 } }
```

Because the row 0 and column 0 were deleted.

The solution i was able to come up by myself is this function which works fine and does what it is supposed to do, but I want a smaller, more compact solution that makes more sense.

```
public Matrix subMatrix(int _i, int _j)
{
    Matrix result = new Matrix(_rows - 1, _cols - 1);
    try
    {
        if (isSquare())
        {
            List<float> listMatrix = new List<float>();
            for (int i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < _cols; j++)
                {
                    if (i != _i && j != _j)
                    {
                        listMatrix.Add(matrix[i, j]);
                    }
                }
            int x = -1;
            int y = 0;
            int z = 0;
            foreach (var item in listMatrix)
            {
                if (y % (result._rows) == 0)
                {
                    x++;
                    y = 0;
                }
                result.matrix[x, y] = item;
                y++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

    return result;
}
```

BTW Matrix is a class I made which is basically a 2D array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short example of some different approach.

```csharp
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float[,] arr = { {0, 2, 7 },
                         {3, 1, 0 },
                         {6, 2, 4 } };
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        float[,] arr2 = SubMatrix(arr, x, y);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr2[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static float[,] SubMatrix(float[,] matrix, int x, int y)
    {
        float[,] result = new float[matrix.GetLength(0) - 1, matrix.GetLength(1) - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < result.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                result[i, j] = matrix[i >= x ? i + 1 : i, j >= y ? j + 1 : j];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output

```
1 0
2 4
```